# How to extend parameter types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

How can I make `prop2` in `effect` either optional or required depending on the specific instance of this class?

```
interface EffectParams {
  prop1: string;
  prop2?: string;
  prop3?: string;
}

interface WithProp2 extends EffectParams {
  prop2: string
}


class Class1 {
  effect: (params: EffectParams) => void;

  constructor(effect: (params: EffectParams) => void) {
    this.effect = effect;
  }
}

const a = new Class1(
  // ERROR HERE
  // Argument of type '({ prop1, prop2 }: WithProp2) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(params: EffectParams) => void'.
  ({ prop1, prop2 }: WithProp2) => {
    prop2.anotherProperty();
    // Can anotherProperty be used without optional chaining?
  }
);

const b = new Class1(
  ({ prop1, prop2 }: EffectParams) => {
    prop2?.anotherProperty();
    // more code
  }
);
```

Comment: Here the problem is that this.effect() will be called with an object that may not have prop2, and when you create your first object you are telling that the function you provide must receive an object that has `props2` which is not available inside EffectParams

Comment: Then, is what I am trying to implement impossible?

Comment: If i understood well, what you want is to provide a function to Class1 which will be usable later, does the params matter ?

Comment: well I don't think what you want and what you are asking for are the same thing, here the props are being specified as the arguments to a callback, somewhere in the class that effect will be called and according to the class specification the argument passed to that effect may or may not have `prop2`, whether it is "required" or not doesn't entirely make sense to specify at the instantiation of the class.

Comment: where does that data for `EffectParam` actually come from? like will it eventually be created by another method on the class instance? in that case you could add a generic on the class to carry around that info but I'm not convinced that is the workflow given the naming of the variables involved

Comment: I want to create a function that will check that it receives `{prop1, prop2}` for instance `a` and  `{prop2, prop2?}` for instance `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed tha name a bit but here is how i would do it

```
interface UserEffectParams {
        name: string;
        age?: number
    }

interface CustomerEffectParams extends Required<UserEffectParams> {
    email: string;
}

class EffectManager<EffectParams extends UserEffectParams> {
    effect: (params: EffectParams) => void;

    constructor(effect: (params: EffectParams) => void) {
            this.effect = effect;
    }
} 

const a = new EffectManager<UserEffectParams>(({ name, age }) => {
    console.log({ name, age });
});
const b = new EffectManager<CustomerEffectParams>(({ name, age, email }) => {
    console.log({ name, age, email });
});
```